# Trouble getting my Android Studio application to run

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got this application to run previously, but since I clicked 'End Task' on Android Studio in the Task Manager in the middle of importing something, it's not working anymore.

deleted screenshot

The problem is in the screenshot above. The run button is greyed out. I can go to Run in top menu --> click Run, it throws up a box prompting me to edit configurations. I click on that, then click Run in the box it throws up, but nothing happens.

My java classes have a red icon next to them, whereas in other applications, they have a blue icon with a letter C. That looks to be the problem.

Anyone know what the problem could be? If you need more information, I am happy to give that.

Comment: You might want to edit the configuration like you say above or just create a new project?

Comment: Just fixed the problem, it's working. I had to import a bunch of stuff into a new project. The application is running now. :)

Comment: Good to hear that it is working

Comment: Hey, I see that you're new to Stack Overflow. If you've fixed your own problem, please leave the solution as an answer so future users with a similar problem can follow your steps to fix it, and also so that this questions will appear as solved and people like me will know it's solved without having to click the link and read you question. Don't just leave an edit to the question. Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: This was sorted out going to File --> New --> Import Project, clicking Next on each window, then 'Finish'. Then Run in the top bar, click 'Run', application runs successfully.